# How to auto respond to email in outlook C# Code

Tags: c#, .net, automation, vsto, outlook-addin

I am using visual studio 2017 installed office development pack,want to create a plugin which responds based on incoming email.
Basically I am tying to monitor an Infra support mailbox ,which forwards the email to concerned team based on the incoming message content.

Any suggestion on how this can be done

Comment: If you aim to create a VSTO add-in, here's some useful howtos for [performing an action when e-mail is received](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268998.aspx) and [sending e-mails](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268749.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways for implementing the required functionality:

1. Use rules for setting up forward rules. You can do that manually in Outlook and programmatically as well. The Outlook object model provides all the required classes for that, see [How to: Create a Rule to Assign Categories to Mail Items Based on Multiple Words in the Subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff424472.aspx) for more information.
2. Use the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/application-newmailex-event-outlook) event for handling incoming emails. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID represented by the `EntryIDCollection` parameter passed to call the `NameSpace.GetItemFromID` method and process the item. In the event handler, you may check the email received and forward the email programmatically. The [Forward](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-forward-method-outlook) method of the MailItem class executes the `Forward` action for an item and returns the resulting copy as a MailItem object.

```
 Sub RemoveAttachmentBeforeForwarding() 
   Dim myinspector As Outlook.Inspector 
   Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
   Dim myattachments As Outlook.Attachments 
   Set myinspector = Application.ActiveInspector 
   If Not TypeName(myinspector) = "Nothing" Then 
     Set myItem = myinspector.CurrentItem.Forward 
     Set myattachments = myItem.Attachments 
     While myattachments.Count > 0 
       myattachments.Remove 1 
     Wend 
     myItem.Display 
     myItem.Recipients.Add "Dan Wilson" 
     myItem.Send 
   Else 
     MsgBox "There is no active inspector." 
   End If 
 End Sub
```

You may find the [How To: Respond to an Outlook email programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/05/how-to-respond-to-an-email-programmatically/) article helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This code using a event to incoming mails to the default inbox

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;        
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    Outlook.NameSpace outlookNameSpace;
    Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox;
    Outlook.Items items;
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        inbox = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
                OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

        items = inbox.Items;
        items.ItemAdd +=
            new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(items_ItemAdd);
    }

    void items_ItemAdd(object Item)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;
        if (Item != null)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem replyMail = mail.Reply();
            //Do your response
            mail.Send();
        }

    }
}
```